# Resharper 5 - enable/disable on the fly

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I want to disable ReSharper 5 when debugging - it slows things down more than I'm willing to take.

Is there an automatic way to do this?

The next best thing would be a toolbar button to manually enable/disable it.

On the Tools -> Options -> ReSharper page there's a comment that the VS command Resharper_ToggleSuspended would do just this. 
[image]

The problem is, I can't find the command when I right-click a toolbar -> Customize... -> 'Commands' tab -> Choose 'Resharper' category.

[alt text http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/1928/commands.png](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/1928/commands.png)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like customization dialog doesn't show commands which doesn't belong to some "category", and ReSharper_ToggleSuspended doesn't have any. Try this:

- Using Tools | Options | Keyboard
  assign shortcut to the command (it is
  listed there), and use shortcut
  instead.
- or, Create simple macro which    will
  execute the command by name, and
  put that macro on the toolbar.